# Procesamiento de Formulario HTML para PHP

Tags: php, json, php7

Me envían desde un formulario externo en html a mi archivo en php llamado proceso.php. Tengo la dificultad de no saber cuales son los nombres de los campos con sus valores. De que forma puedo saber que variables y valores trae este? Hay forma de transformar esos campos y valores directamente a JSON sin saber sus nombre?

Comment: mirar los `ID` de los imputs del form que te envia los datos

Comment: El form viene sin el detalle de ID. En caso de que llegara como podria hacer el recorrido en php?

Comment: var_dump($_REQUEST), si sabes el método puedes hacerlo directamente de $_POST o $_GET. Puedes recorrerlo con un bucle tipo foreach.

Comment: Prueba <?php print_r($_POST); ?>

Comment: con var_dump me arroja esto: array(3) { ["codigoEncuesta"]=> string(6) "ENC111" ["cedula"]=> string(8) "12345678" ["PR1"]=> string(13) "Es un planeta" }

Comment: Se puede convertir directamente a JSON?

Comment: Si puedes convertir a json, te aconsejo que al ser strings compruebes el tipo de codificación ya que para json_encode debería ser utf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con este código puedes saber si te envían los datos por el método GET o POST

```
$Metodo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
```

Así puedes obtener las claves de los campos que te llegan:

```
$campos = array_keys(${"_" . $Metodo}));
```

En caso de que ya sepas el método por el que te llegan los campos sólo pones

```
$campos = array_keys($_GET);
$campos = array_keys($_POST);
```

si deseas recorrerlos puedes usar un for each así:

```
foreach ($campos as $Key => $val) {
}
```

Si deseas convertir los datos recibidos a JSON puedes usar la función json_encode() de PHP, dependiendo de si conoces o no el método

```
$datosJson = json_encode(${"_" . $Metodo});
$datosJson = json_encode($_GET);
$datosJson = json_encode($_POST);
```

Saludos.